# One to Many with two Properties from the same class

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following classes that I would really like to map correctly in EF:

```
internal class Wallet : EntityFrameworkEntity
{
    public Wallet()
    {
        this.Requests = new List<FinancialRequest>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal CurrentBalance { get; set; }
    public decimal BlockedBalance { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Paper> Papers { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FinancialRequest> Requests { get; set; }

    public virtual User Manager { get; set; }

}

internal class Request : EntityFrameworkEntity
{
    public Int64 UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public RequestStatus Status { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

internal class FinancialRequest : Request
{
    public DateTime ValidUntil { get; set; }
    public FinancialRequestType RequestType { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public bool UseMarketValue { get; set; }
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Wallet Source { get; set; }
    public virtual Wallet Destination { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Code First, so this is my method that maps those classes:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Wallet>()
                    .HasMany(x => x.Requests)
                    .WithOptional();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Wallet>()
                    .HasMany(x => x.Papers)
                    .WithOptional(x => x.Owner)
                    .Map(configuration => configuration.MapKey("OwnerId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Wallet>()
                    .HasMany(x => x.Requests)
                    .WithOptional();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Request>().ToTable("Requests");
        modelBuilder.Entity<FinancialRequest>().ToTable("FinancialRequests");

        modelBuilder.Entity<FinancialRequest>()
                    .HasRequired(x => x.Team)
                    .WithOptional()
                    .Map(configuration => configuration.MapKey("TeamId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<FinancialRequest>()
                    .HasOptional(x => x.Destination)
                    .WithOptionalDependent()
                    .Map(configuration => configuration.MapKey("DestinationWalletId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<FinancialRequest>()
                    .HasRequired(x => x.Source)
                    .WithRequiredDependent()
                    .Map(configuration => configuration.MapKey("SourceWalletId"));
```

If I leave this mapping the way it's now, my database schema looks like this:

[image: Wrong database schema]

If you look carefully, you'll see that there's a column called "Wallet_Id" that it's not suposed to be there. This column only exists because the Wallet class has the "Requests" collection. 
If I remove the collection from the the columns goes away, but I need this collection! It representes a importante relation between the classes. What I don't need is the 3rd column in the database wrongly generated.

Does anybody knows how can I avoid this? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you really want `Source` and `Destination` in a *one-to-one* relationship? Somehow I would expect that a wallet can be the source and destination of *many* financial requests. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Slauma: Actually, it's not a one-to-one. It's a many-to-one, but this is the only way I can map Source and Destination, One Wallet can have 0 or N FinancialRequests but I can only map from the other side. Or is there another way of doig it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that causes the redundant foreign key column `Wallet_Id` is that EF doesn't know if the `Wallet.Requests` collection is the inverse navigation property of `FinancialRequest.Source` or `FinancialRequest.Destination`. Because it cannot decide between the two EF assumes that `Wallet.Requests` doesn't have an inverse navigation property at all. The result is a third redundant one-to-many relationship with the third FK.

Basically you have three options:

- Remove the `Wallet.Requests` collection and the third relationship will disappear (as you already have noticed). But you don't want that.
- Tell EF explicitly if `Wallet.Requests` has `Source` **or** `Destination` as inverse navigation property:

  ```
  // Remove the modelBuilder.Entity<Wallet>().HasMany(x => x.Requests) mapping

  modelBuilder.Entity<FinancialRequest>()
              .HasOptional(x => x.Destination)
              .WithMany(x => x.Requests)
              .Map(config => config.MapKey("DestinationWalletId"));

  modelBuilder.Entity<FinancialRequest>()
              .HasRequired(x => x.Source)
              .WithMany()
              .Map(config => config.MapKey("SourceWalletId"));
  ```

  Use `WithMany(x => x.Requests)` in one of the two (`Destination` in the example, it could also be `Source`), but **not in both**.
- Introduce a second collection in `Wallet` and map the two collections to `Source` and `Destination` respectively:

  ```
  internal class Wallet : EntityFrameworkEntity
  {
      public Wallet()
      {
          this.SourceRequests = new List<FinancialRequest>();
          this.DestinationRequests = new List<FinancialRequest>();
      }

      // ...

      public virtual ICollection<FinancialRequest> SourceRequests { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<FinancialRequest> DestinationRequests { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  Mapping:

  ```
  // Remove the modelBuilder.Entity<Wallet>().HasMany(x => x.Requests) mapping

  modelBuilder.Entity<FinancialRequest>()
              .HasOptional(x => x.Destination)
              .WithMany(x => x.DestinationRequests)
              .Map(config => config.MapKey("DestinationWalletId"));

  modelBuilder.Entity<FinancialRequest>()
              .HasRequired(x => x.Source)
              .WithMany(x => x.SourceRequests)
              .Map(config => config.MapKey("SourceWalletId"));
  ```

BTW: Shouldn't *both* `Source` and `Destination` be required? If yes, you can replace the `HasOptional` by `HasRequired` but you must append `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` to at least one of the two mappings to avoid a multiple cascading delete path exception.

Comment: First, thank you for your effort Slauma. I'm trying a DDD approach to my development. I don't want to remove the Requests lists because most of the times I'm going to query FinancialRequest from this property. The FinancialRequest process will happen in 2 fases, so I can only force the Source as not null. The Destination will be populated only if a few rules are validated.

Comment: Continuing: Adding another list to my Wallet classes is weird because it does not have any meaning for the domain. There's only one set of Requests that have 2 properties of type Wallet that mean completelly different things and are used in different places in the system. I think that this is a real problem for EF since I've implemented the same domain in NHibernate and did not have any problems. One class just cannot have more than 1 property from another class in a one-to-many relationship. :/